# Restfm with special character search in filemaker database

Tags: php, filemaker

I am using [**`RESTfm`**](http://www.restfm.com/). I have one layout of users having email ids. I want to search the users using the email but the api gives the response:-

> "X-RESTfm-FM-Status":"401" No records match the request.

**Example**

I search with *xyz@gmail.com*. If i try to search only gmail.com for the same field it works.

The API URL is below.

```
http://localhost/RESTfm/database/layout/TestTable.json?&RFMmax=15&RFMsF1=Name&RFMsV1=xyz@gmail.com
```

I just want to know if restfm does this type of special character searches or not.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about RestFM, but I see in the [documentation](http://www.restfm.com/restfm-manual/web-api-reference-documentation/uri-restfmdatabaselayoutlayout/read-get) that the find criterion "*should be in the same format as a FileMaker Find.*"

To perform the same find within FileMaker, you need to escape the `@` character and make the find criterion `xyz\@gmail.com`.